# SSRS report with multiple data sources

Tags: reporting-services

I am not much aware of SSRS report.
In my project SSRS report is generating the pdf with empty data.

Question:

My SSRS report is using two data sources say ds1 and ds2

if the query for ds1 throws a timeout error and ds2 returns the data, will it generate the SSRS report with ds2 (the fileds which use ds1 shows empty).?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. Once a dataset fails, the reporting processing fails. We have issues with an hourly log shipping to a database that knocks it offline for 5 minutes an hour - this kills reports each time.